# how to change element with jquery window resize event

Tags: jquery

Jquery carousel plugin `slickslider` has been used to show slider in project

```
$(".regular").slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

Now I want to customize`slidesToShow` option according `window width` with the help of jquery `resize` function. How to insert following requirement in above function. I'd tried inserting, but doesn't work, other jquery function also stopped.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    slidesToShow: 3,
  }
  else {
    slidesToShow: 2,
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) already has responsive web design support. There is no need for another resize listener.

For your case this is how you might want to use it:

```
$(".regular").slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 960,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

By the way you have syntax error in your code. It's usually a good idea to learn the language before using it.

Comment: I'd missed while typing in forum, it is correct in editor. Whatever, great tips, learned new thing about slick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't just dump data to javascript, you need an action to achieve something. The following might work - I don't know the slick plugin ..

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $(".regular").slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
  }
  else {
    $(".regular").slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some like this:

```
function slickslider_init(elements_to_show) {
    $(".regular").slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: elements_to_show,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($(window).width() < 960) {
      slickslider_init(3),
   } else {
      slickslider_init(2),
   }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    slickslider_init(3),
  }
  else {
    slickslider_init(2),
 }
});
```